# Unable to understand how to upload my application to the Xamarin test cloud

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nunit, coded-ui-tests, xamarin-test-cloud

I have added the UITesting project to an existing project which did not include UI  Testing initially.I am using Xamarin Studio.
I am unable to upload the app to test cloud for testing for some reason. I have tested the app on the local device by writing the tests. I did choose **Debug configuration** and set **development** provisioning profiles in the options . I have also selected **'Signing Identity'** in   **'iOS Bundle Signing'** project option to point to my developer certificate.
When I right click on the tests to run on the cloud it is asking me to **upload the package**.

MY QUESTIONS:

1. What do they mean by package? Do they mean IPA? I did not see this when I made the sample project which had UI test enabled in it by default.It uploaded by app on its own.
   [image]

2.When I select my IPA for the above browse button my IPA is disabled in grey colour and I cannot select it. Do I need to change some of the settings for test Cloud. (REMEMBER **I have checked the tests on my device and they are working good, I wish to test on the test Cloud now**)?

3. Do i need to have a specific setting which would make my app uploadable to the testcloud?

Please ask me if more information is required. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the APK or IPA.

> Select the APK or the IPA to submit along with the tests, and then click the Upload and Run button. Xamarin Studio will then proceed to compile the UITest project and upload the test assembly along with the APK or IPA to Xamarin Test Cloud.

This is directly from the Xamarin documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/submitting-tests-to-xamarin-test-cloud/#Submitting_UITests_for_an_External_Mobile_App

You can also upload the Tests directly from Xamarin Studio:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/submitting-tests-to-xamarin-test-cloud/#Submitting_UITests_From_a_Xamarin_Solution